# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot create item with duplicate id - My id is coming from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, contextmenu

Trying to display in my contextmenu a list of playlists that exist in my firebase realtime database so that I can save data to that playlist. I am able to display them for my page contexts but it won't for images or quotes contexts.

I get this error for each playist's id in the console:

Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot create item with duplicate id -MMqelZvPmCUbuMCxQ42

How can i display my playlists on all contexts without running into this error.

Here is the code :

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    var uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    //contextmenu for page CHANGE REPO TO MOST RECENT PLAYLIST -------------
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      title: "Repo",
      contexts: ["page"],
      onclick: MyGenericClick,
    });
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      title: "Repo",
      contexts: ["image"],
      onclick: MyImageClick,
    });
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      title: "Repo",
      contexts: ["selection"],
      onclick: MyQuoteClick,
    });
    //playlist contextmenu from database
    database
      .ref(uid)
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
          // display existing playlists
          chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: childSnapshot.val().idKey,
            title: childSnapshot.val().name,
            contexts: ["page"],
            onclick: MyPagePlaylistClick,
          });
          chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: childSnapshot.val().idKey,
            title: childSnapshot.val().name,
            contexts: ["image"],
            onclick: MyImagePlaylistClick,
          });
          chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: childSnapshot.val().idKey,
            title: childSnapshot.val().name,
            contexts: ["selection"],
            onclick: MySelectionPlaylistClick,
          });
        });
      });
  } else {
    console.log("No user is signed in.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the exact API you are using, my hunch is you need to make each `id` unique in your database call; currently you are using the same `childSnapshot.val().idKey` for each entry.  Try something like

```
          chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: childSnapshot.val().idKey + '-page',
            title: childSnapshot.val().name,
            contexts: ["page"],
            onclick: MyPagePlaylistClick,
          });
          chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: childSnapshot.val().idKey + '-image',
            title: childSnapshot.val().name,
            contexts: ["image"],
            onclick: MyImagePlaylistClick,
          });
          chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: childSnapshot.val().idKey + '-selection',
            title: childSnapshot.val().name,
            contexts: ["selection"],
            onclick: MySelectionPlaylistClick,
          });
```

to make each `id` entry more unique.